# Optimal weights subset sum using backtracking

Tags: swift, algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to solve a problem. I have some weights. `[2,7,20,70,200,700]`
After a given input, for example `1507`, it should return the **optimal** combination of those weights. Which in this case would be `[700,200,200,200,200,7]`. Unfortunately my algorithm is returning `[700, 700, 70, 20, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`. When I say **optimal** I mean that my algorithm should use the fewest number of weights as possible.

```
func solve(_ targetValue: Int, weights: inout [Int]) -> [Int] {
    // The used weights to store
    var usedWeights: [Int] = []
    // The current total value for the calculation
    var total = targetValue
    // If target value is 0 add it to the array and just return it
    if targetValue == 0 { usedWeights.append(0); return usedWeights }
    // Loop through the weights
    for weight in weights.reversed() {

    while weight <= total {
            total -= weight
            usedWeights.append(weight)
        }
    }    // If still weights are not found call the function recursively again but remove the last element before
    if total != 0 {
        weights.removeLast()
        return solve(targetValue, weights: &weights)
    }
    return usedWeights
}

var newWeights: [Int] = [2,7,20,70,200,700]
print(solve(1507, weights: &newWeights))
```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong? The important thing is to solve it using backtracking. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: FYI - your check for 1, 3, and 5 is unnecessary. Besides, those weights might get passed in.

Comment: Yeah thats true, but I check it because I only have the above weights.

Comment: Take out those checks. It doesn't matter whether you have those weights or not. You don't have weights for lots of other values either.

Comment: But if I dont check it it will use a lot of weights

Comment: This is basically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem, right?

Comment: Well, I think your termination condition is based on "If i have a path with some cost then terminate.". You should terminate the loop only if you have all the open nodes with cost greater than the cost of founded path's cost. This problem is common.

Comment: Yeah seems to be the same I just want to solve it with backtracking @AlexQueue

Comment: Yeah I change it @rmaddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible recursive solution:

```
// Find the shortest combination of (possibly repeating) numbers in `values`
// whose sum is exactly `target`, and whose count is less than `limit`.
// Return `nil` if no such combination exist.
//
// `target` must be non-negative, and `values` an array of positive
// numbers in decreasing order.
//
func solveHelper(target: Int, values: ArraySlice<Int>, limit: Int) -> [Int]? {
    if target == 0 {
        return [] // Target reached exactly.
    }
    guard let first = values.first else {
        return nil // No values left, target cannot be reached.
    }
    if target/first >= limit {
        return nil // Target cannot be reached with less than `limit` values.
    }

    var best: [Int]? = nil   // Best solution found so far
    var bestCount = limit // Number of values in best solution

    for n in stride(from: target/first, through: 0, by: -1) {
        if let s = solveHelper(target: target - n * first, values: values.dropFirst(), limit: bestCount - n) {
            best = s + repeatElement(first, count: n)
            bestCount = s.count + n
        }
    }

    return best
}

// Find the shortest combination of (possibly repeating) values in `values`
// whose sum is exactly `target`. Return `nil` if no such combination exist.
//
// `target` must be non-negative, and `values` an array of positive
// numbers.
//
func solve(target: Int, values: [Int]) -> [Int]? {
    return solveHelper(target: target, values: ArraySlice(values.sorted(by: >)), limit: Int.max)
}
```

Examples:

```
print(solve(target: 1507, values: [2, 7, 20, 70, 200, 700]) as Any)
// Optional([7, 200, 200, 200, 200, 700])

print(solve(target: 1507, values: [20, 70, 200, 700]) as Any)
// nil

print(solve(target: 6, values: [1, 3, 4]) as Any)
// Optional([3, 3])

print(solve(target: 0, values: [1, 3, 4]) as Any)
// Optional([])
```

Some explanations:

- It is assumed that `target` is non-negative and that all `values`
  are positive.
- `solve` sorts the array in descending order and passes it as an
  `ArraySlice` to the recursive helper function. This helps to avoid
  further copies of the element storage, when `values.dropFirst()`
  is passed to the recursive call.
- `solveHelper` starts “greedy” with the maximal possible number of
  the first (i.e. largest) value, calls itself recursively for the
  remaining target sum and values, then repeats the process with less
  copies of the first value, keeping track of the shortest solution found
  so far.
- In order to “prune” the recursion tree, a `limit` is passed
  to the recursive call. As an example, if `1507 = 700 + 200 + 200 + 200 + 200 + 7` has already been found then there is no need anymore to sum only values in `[2, 7, 20, 70]`, that would only give longer solutions.
- The function runs reasonably fast in my tests for the given array.
  For a larger number of possible values you probably need a more
  sophisticated algorithm, such as the dynamic programming approach
  described in [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. I solved it as well using dynamic programming, but my solution is much slower then yours. As well thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @martin-r is there any non repitive solution ?